# How to callback several variables from a page using jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have spent hours(maybe days) on this problem. I know this question has been asked before but the answers are always so vague for my beginner experience level to understand. I would love some specific and simplified code exampes.

I am submitting an AJAX call to changeDate.php.

**index.html**

```
$(document).on("click", "#day-left", function(event){
    changeDate = changeDate - 1;

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "changeDate.php",
            data: {
                amount: changeDate,
                loginName: "benjamin_lawson"
            },

            success: function(data) {
            $("#date").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

This page receives the ajax. Using the data it updates SQL and creates 24 variables ($hour1, $hour2, $hour3...) with data.

**changeDate.php**

```
<?php
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$user = $_POST['loginName'];
//server information variables

$dateName = date("mdY", strtotime("+" . $amount . " day"));


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

for ($x = 1; $x <= 24; $x++) {
    $sql = "SELECT `$dateName` FROM `$user` WHERE hour='$x'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             ${"hour" . $x} = $row[$dateName];
         }
    }
    }
//this creates 24 variables with all my information I want sent 
//through my call back. ($hour1, $hour2, $hour3,...)
```

How can I pass these variables back to my first page in a callback that keeps the variable name and variable data?

I see a related question to this and they answered with:

**RELATED QUESTION AND ANSWER**... potential solution

> You can return arbitrarily many variables with json_encode().
>
> Try in your PHP:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array($num1, $num2));
?>
You can add to that array , $num3, $num4, ... and so on.
```

> In your JS, you can access each number as follows.
>
> First, you will need this line of code to parse the encoded JSON string, in > > your success function.
>
> var result = $.parseJSON(output);
>
> That sets result as a JSON object. Now you can access all fields within > result:
>
> result[0] -- $num1 in PHP
>   result[1] -- $num2 in PHP

I would really appreciate if someone can show me in code what I need to do to make this work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well every answer is telling to use JSON encode of php. And you required another answers, though theres is already existing a question on that.

Well from php, you can return any data you want. Either you can give a string, or directly HTML or some formatted data like xml or JSON.

Whatever echoed/printed from that request is a response. You can do that request directly from URL or by AJAX. If the request meets the prerequisites, it will show same response.

Now if you just echo any data, there JS no structure and probably you would have to format and parse it to extract meaningful data from it.

But JSON and XML are the know data transport languages. XML is good but needs structuring at server and element based retrieval at client side (there can be many efficient ways which I am unknown to; as I am not a fan of XML). For JSON, you have encode and decode methods at server end and JavaScript is like elder brother to it.

Now how do you form a JSON? You just pass array or object to `json_encode` and it will return the JSON string. `echo` that string and your response is ready.

So for I am going to use @Poonam's code; I am making few optimizations also:

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$user = $_POST['loginName'];

//server information variables
$dateName = date("mdY", strtotime("+" . $amount . " day"));

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

for ($x = 1; $x <= 24; $x++) {

}

// fill an array from 1 to 24 with steps of 1
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php
$x = range(1, 24, 1);

$sql = "SELECT `$dateName`, hour FROM `$user` WHERE hour IN ('". implode( "', '", $x ) ."')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$response_arr = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $response_arr['hour' . $row->hour] = $row[$dateName];
     }
}

echo json_encode($response_arr);
exit(0);
//this creates 24 variables with all my information I want sent
```

And in the success callback of AJAX, use either `JSON.parse()` if content type is not mentioned as `application/json`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was easy to follow and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

here i use json to encode data .

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async: false,
        url:"finance/getdataq",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,      
        success: function(data){
// you can access your data variables like data['ukeydt'];
         $("."+targetval).find('.qrwordfol').html(data['ukeydt']);
         $("."+targetval).find('img').attr('src',data['ukeyqr']); 
         $("."+targetval).show();
         return false;  
        },
        error: function (data) {
            getd="";
        }
    });
```

and in my php code

```
    public function getdataq()
     {
      $data = array();
     $data['ukeydt'] = "this is first";
     $data['ukeyqr'] = "this is second";
     echo json_encode($data);
     exit(); 

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but to be honest this still confuses me. Can you show me a very simple example using what I am trying to do? Import simple variable names ($hour1, $hour2) and then use them back where I called the AJAX?

Comment: you need to store your all values in an array and then you can encode this array and return this to your jquery ajax function and then you can access them into jquery .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array which will have all values for hours.

In changeDate.php

```
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
$user = $_POST['loginName'];
//server information variables

$dateName = date("mdY", strtotime("+" . $amount . " day"));


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

for ($x = 1; $x <= 24; $x++) {
    $sql = "SELECT `$dateName` FROM `$user` WHERE hour='$x'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $response_arr = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $response_arr['hour' . $x] = $row[$dateName];
         }
    }
    }


echo json_encode($response_arr);
     exit();
    //this creates 24 variables with all my information I want sent 
    //through my call back. ($hour1, $hour2, $hour3,...)
```

This `$response_arr` will have `$response_arr['hour1']...$response_arr['hour24']` and you can use this array in your `success: function(data)`

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
```

You'll get your whole data in `data`

Comment: Great answer, thanks! So I now have my data properly echoed back in to my index as an array. Can you please explain to me how I can now use this data and separate them in to hour1, hour2 variables put them in to variables on the index page?

Comment: `var hour1 = data['hour1'];   var hour2 = data['hour2'];` And so on. This will work fine.